# How to render in Unity without the editor/scene/player being visible?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In my Android-Unity app I have some data such as text, text size, text coordinates etc that I will use to create the output and store it as a screenshot I will later use in my app.

But I need to make this happen when the user isn't seeing the Unity player/scene. So my question is that is it possible to render the contents and then take a screenshot of the same without the user seeing the Unity editor/player/scene whatever one may call it? Is there a way to do it in the background? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to take a screenshot of elements that are not on screen, you'll probably just want to have a secondary "screenshot camera". You can use a cullingmask to render only parts of your scene to this camera.

Comment: @ErikOverflow Thanks a lot for the suggestion. When you say, "You can use a cullingmask to render only parts of your scene to this camera." does it mean that my scene is visible but I can take screenshot of a part of scene which isn't visible? 

My requirement is that the scene should not be visible at all. Can I can achieve that with this approach. Sorry I am new to Unity.

Comment: You can have a bunch of objects in the same "place" of the game, but have them placed on different layers. Your cameras use the culling mask to determine what layer's they render. If your main camera (the camera displaying the screen) is configured to ignore a layer, then it won't render it. However, if you have a duplicate camera that includes that layer in its culling mask, that duplicated camera will.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish but I can clarify the use of a culling mask here. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejxEv.png) is what the scene looks like. I have embedded the view from Camera 2 into the bottom left of the game. You can see that Camera 2 is not displaying the floor. This is because I set it's culling to only respond to objects tagged with a custom layer [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOHBA.png). Where as the Main Camera's culling mask is set to everything. Now, anything I tag with the "Custom" layer will be visible in the second camera and everything else would not be. I'm assuming what you want to do from here is to tag the things you want visible when you take a screenshot with a specific layer, then set the Culling Mask of your "Screenshot Camera" to that layer and take a screenshot with that Camera. That way you can specify what Objects/UI want visible in that camera.